# Can't modify times one a time without weird errors

Tags: php, datetime, multidimensional-array

I've got free time that any given employee has right now pulled from their calendar into a multi-dimensional array where each [i][] is a pair of dates that indicate the start time [i][0] and end time [i][1] of a free block of time. I need to take that and divide it into 20 min intervals between the start and end time of the block and return all times in that format. Right now I am just constantly modifying the same object on repeat but for the correct amount of iterations and its driving me insane... hope y'all can help.

I've tried everything my c++ knowledge base has provided but php uses objects by reference I guess and I cant find a way around it.

```php
$test = array_chunk($times, 2);
$i = 0;
$end_test = count($times)/2;
$free_slots = array();
$interval = '+20 minutes';
array_push($free_slots, $test[0][0]);
for($i=0;$i<$end_test;$i++){
    $test1 = clone $test[$i][0];
    $test2 = clone $test[$i][1];
    while($test1<=$test2){
        $test1->modify($interval);
        array_push($free_slots, $test1);
    }
}
```

So after I pair the dates into couplets and run the code I pasted the first time is correct, then it spews into chaos:

```
08:00:00.000000",10:20:00.000000", 10:20:00.000000", 10:20:00.000000", 10:20:00.000000", 10:20:00.000000", 10:20:00.000000", 10:20:00.000000", 12:20:00.000000", 12:20:00.000000", 12:20:00.000000",  12:20:00.000000", 16:20:00.000000", etc...
```

and the array of datetime objects that have the start and end times stored for the free blocks looks like this:

```
[0][0]="2019-08-14 08:00:00.000000"
[0][1]="2019-08-14 10:00:00.000000"
[1][0]="2019-08-14 11:00:00.000000"
[1][1]="2019-08-14 12:00:00.000000"
[2][0]="2019-08-14 13:00:00.000000"
[2][1]="2019-08-14 16:00:00.000000"
[3][0]="2019-08-14 17:00:00.000000"
[3][1]="2019-08-14 19:00:00.000000"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is working for me:

```php
  //split into start and end points
        array_push($times, $last);
        $test = array_chunk($times, 2);
        $free_slots = array();
        $interval = '+20 minutes';
        $end_test = count($times)/2;
        //split into 'x' min intervals
        for($i=0; $i<$end_test; $i++){
            array_push($free_slots, $test[$i][0]);
            $mod = clone $test[$i][0];
            while($mod < $test[$i][1]){
                $m = clone $mod->modify($interval);
                array_push($free_slots, $m);
                if($m != $test[$i][1]){
                    array_push($free_slots, $m);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone `$test1` each time through the inner loop. Otherwise you're just modifying it in place and pushing references to the same objects.

You don't need to clone the original dates when assigning `$test1` and `$test2`, though. You never modify `$test2`, so it doesn't need to be a clone. And you don't modify `$test1` until you get into the loop, after it clones it.

```
for($i=0;$i<$end_test;$i++){
    $test1 = $test[$i][0];
    $test2 = $test[$i][1];
    while($test1<=$test2){
        $test1 = clone $test1;
        $test1->modify($interval);
        array_push($free_slots, $test1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you came up with another solution you should post that as an answer.